# How to print the selected cell's datas in another ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, tableview

I could not figure out how to solve this logical problem. Here is what i need:
In an array, i have the customer names. And i am printing this names in a tableView. When the customer name is tapped, you are being redirected to other viewController which includes the selected customer's orders.

The problem is, i have to store these datas in core data. So customer's names are in an array, also orders are in an array too. But i do not know how to assign two different arrays to each other.

Basically: when customer name is tapped in tableView, it has to push to next viewController which has this tapped customer's orders.

Do i have to do something with database design or assign customer array to order arrays? I am really confused.

Waiting for your suggestions. Thank you!!!

Comment: Upload your tableview cellforrow, didselect, and prpareforsegue if you use. How can anyone help you without uploading code

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you are finding hard to link your each customer with corresponding order array. 
For this, you have array for customer, and create one dictionary whose key is customer name and value is orderArray. So if you tap some customer in table view, you get the corresponding order array from the dictionary which you can pass to next view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood that right. Just do the following stuff.

For Eg:- you have and `Entity` named **OrderInfo** and inside that you have four `Attributes` **customerName, address, orderID and city**.

So what you do is just use ur array with name to list out the things in the `tableView`. Then the logic is simple, like using `didSelectRowAt`, you can get the selected name. Pass this name to the nextVC like.
I will use `storyBoardID` to do that [You can also use your way to pass this].

**First VC:**

```
     let objNextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVC") as! NextVC
    objNextVC.strName = your_selected_NameHere
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objNextVC, animated: true)
```

**NextVC:**

```
var strName:String = String()
```

---

Now here the logic begins, I assume that you have also stored the same name in CoreData [The names that are there in the array of names]. If not i would suggest you to do that to reduce the extra effort from your end.

Now in **NextVC** simply get the name string from the `strName` declared at the top

and apply the following code to get the data.

**CoreData Match and Fetch Query:**

```
func update(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OrderInfo")
    do{
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0{
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
                if let name = result.value(forKey: "customerName") as? String{
                    if name == strName{
                        print(result)
                        let name = result.value(forKey: "customerName")
                        let address = result.value(forKey: "address")
                        let orderID = result.value(forKey: "orderID")
                        let city = result.value(forKey: "city")

                        //Use it the way you like
                        do{
                            try context.save()
                            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                        }
                        catch{
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch{
    }
}
```

And if everything is fine and If data is there. You will get your desired Output.

Cheers!